# Is it possible to print the match of a re.search() used in an if statement?

Tags: python

I need to keep my regex search in an if statement. Is it possible to get the match of my re.search() like this?

```
if re.search(regex,string):
    print(match)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible like this:

```
if match := re.search(regex,string):
    print(match)
```

Python-3.8+ required for [assignment expressions](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/).

Answer (score -1):

```
import re

my_string = "abcdefcddd"
if re.search('c', my_string):
    print("A match found.")
else:
    print('No match')
#or
found = re.search('c', my_string)
print(found.group())
print(found.span()) #index of the first match
```

My guess you may need `re.findall()` or its sister `re.finditer()` if you want to find all the regex matches.

```
matches = re.findall('c', my_string)
print(matches)

matches = re.finditer('c', my_string)
for match in matches:
    print(match)
```

Maybe check and see what exactly you need. Python documentation should help.